# PyTorch data/wieght type mismatch event after calling tensor.to(torch.float)

Tags: python, pytorch

As title, how to solve the issue?
OS: Ubuntu 16.04
Python version: 3.8
torch version: 1.10.1

```
# Instantiate the neural network and optimizer
net = InceptionNetModel()
net.to(device)
optimizer = optim.Adam(net.parameters(), lr=0.01)
criterion = nn.BCELoss()

# Train the neural network
for epoch in range(500):
    net.train()
    iteration = 0
    for batch_idx, (apc_batch, pump_batch, vent_batch, kpc_batch, dms_batch, info_batch, y_batch) in enumerate(
            train_tabular_dataloader):
        apc_batch, pump_batch, vent_batch, kpc_batch, dms_batch, info_batch, label_batch = \
            apc_batch.to(device, torch.float64), pump_batch.to(device, torch.float64), vent_batch.to(device, torch.float64), kpc_batch.to(device, torch.float64), dms_batch.to(device, torch.float64), info_batch.to(device, torch.float64), y_batch.to(device, torch.float64)

        optimizer.zero_grad()
        y_pred = net(apc_batch, pump_batch, vent_batch, kpc_batch, dms_batch, info_batch)
```

returns error message:

```
 File "/home/user/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/conv.py", line 446, in forward
    return self._conv_forward(input, self.weight, self.bias)
  File "/home/user/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/conv.py", line 442, in _conv_forward
    return F.conv2d(input, weight, bias, self.stride,
RuntimeError: Input type (torch.cuda.DoubleTensor) and weight type (torch.cuda.FloatTensor) should be the same
```

Comment: I think you should cast your float64 data to float32

Comment: If you can modify the loader, read data as float rather than double.